# How do you reprocess your images for an existing image in Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I already have a `user` in the database that was created using `remote_avatar_url` and two images were processed - medium and large versions.  But now the user needs the capability to change their images with another `remote_avatar_url`.  When I do this the image is not being reprocessed.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

users.rb

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.remote_image_url = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
  user.save
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the re processing of versions

```
instance = MyUploader.new
instance.recreate_versions!
```

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#recreating-versions